# How to group box-and-whisker in parallel for comparison in BoxWhiskerChart?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, legending, plotting, labeling

I have two collections of data: `xdata` and `ydata`

```
xdata = { {"A", {1, 2, 5}}, {"B", {5, 7, 2, 2, 5}}, {"C", {3, 2, 5, 7}}};
ydata = { {"A", {7, 2}}, {"B", {7, 2, 5}}, {"C", {6, 7, 3}}};
```

Using `BoxWhiskerChart`, I can show `xdata` or `ydata` *alone*:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[xdata, 
 {{"Whiskers", Dashed}, {"Outliers", None}, {"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thick, White]}}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, ChartStyle -> 56, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: alone]

Now I want to group the data according to their labels (i.e., `A`, `B`, and `C`).
The resulting figure (with the same faked data) is like [this (in Python) @ stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598291/1833118):

[image: group]

Thus, my question is:

> How to group box-and-whisker in parallel for comparison in BoxWhiskerChart?
>
> In particular, how to show the labels (`A`, `B`, and `C`) in `x-axis` and how to draw the legends (`xdata` and `ydata`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an example exactly like this in the documentation for `BoxWhiskerChart`. All you need to do is reshape your data into a list of doubles:

```
xdata = {{"A", {1, 2, 5}}, {"B", {5, 7, 2, 2, 5}}, {"C", {3, 2, 5, 7}}};
ydata = {{"A", {7, 2}}, {"B", {7, 2, 5}}, {"C", {6, 7, 3}}};

labels = {xdata[[All, 1]], None}

xdata = xdata[[All, 2]];
ydata = ydata[[All, 2]];

data = Transpose@{xdata, ydata}

style = Sequence[{
  {"Whiskers", Dashed},
  {"Outliers", None},
  {"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thick, White]}},
  ChartStyle -> 56,
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  ChartLegends -> {"x", "y"},
  ChartLabels -> labels];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, style]
```

> [image: BWChart]

Comment: @Karsten Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Would you please help me with [this problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69358/22068) also related to `BoxWhiskerChart`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comment for people who already have functioning `BoxWhiskerCharts` and just want to add the group labels—you can indeed just do:

`BoxWhiskerChart[{{{"LabelA",{dataA1,dataA2,...}},{"LabelB",{dataB1,dataB2,...}},...]`